# Automate selenium webdriver python onclick javascript double confirmation

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Im new using Selenium Webdriver and i couldn't automate a confirmation javascript onclick button, these button can't inspect to see the xpath;

the html button is:

`<input type="button" class="ButtonEnable" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Borrar todos los contadores " onclick="javascript:CallBack_Reset()">`
and i try with the name or id

**web_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Reset').click()**

but appear a pop-up window with a confirmation

Comment: Please add code that you've already tried and link to the website you're trying to automate

Answer (score 0):

Update. I resolve it.

I use a selenium condition (alert) to javascript callback push-up windows.

the code to resolve it:

`web_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Reset').click() WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present(), '¿Desea borrar todos los contadores?') alert = driver.switch_to.alert alert.accept()`